# In WPF animation set property BeginTime to a static resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, resources

What I want to do is define all the BeginTimes of my Animation using a resource.

For example, I want:

```
<sys:TimeSpan x:key="SomeResource">... </sys:TimeSpan>

...

<DoubleAnimation BeginTime={StaticResource SomeResource}/>
```

Obviously sys:TimeSpan is not the correct type to use.  How do I define my resource so I can reference it as a resource when defining my animations?

I also want to do this purely in XAML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.TimeSpan` is the correct type to use since is this is the type of `BeginTime`. You can also do the same for `Duration` (but using the `System.Windows.Duration` type instead).

Here is an example using a `StaticResource` in an animation (after 2 seconds, fade in for 1 second):

```
    <Button Content="Placeholder"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Opacity="0.5">
        <Button.Resources>
            <sys:TimeSpan x:Key="FadeInBeginTime">0:0:2</sys:TimeSpan>
            <Duration x:Key="FadeInDuration">0:0:1</Duration>
        </Button.Resources>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FadeInBeginStoryBoard">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 To="1"
                                                 BeginTime="{StaticResource FadeInBeginTime}"
                                                 Duration="{StaticResource FadeInDuration}" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeInBeginStoryBoard" />
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Assuming you have declared the `sys` namespace as:

```
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: System.TimeSpan does indeed work.  Thank you very much for the answer.  I was struggling to find the correct type to use, and must have did something silly when I had tried TimeSpan earlier.

Comment: Note that this does not work in Silverlight, apparently ... gives a native exception.