# WPF XAML Designer Error with Datatype Duration - Build successful but still throws error though

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, duration, incompatibletypeerror

this is my first question here, so I hope I am precise and clear enough.

I am developing a WPF application and created a UserControl with UserControl.Resources, where I defined Storyboards and recurring values as StaticResources.
Some of those recurring values are **Durations** for animations.
So, for example I have two StaticResources such as:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

   <Duration x:Key="DurationOpacity">0:0:2</Duration>

   <Storyboard x:Key="Listening">
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1.0" To="0.3" Duration="{StaticResource DurationOpacity}" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />        
   </Storyboard>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

When I build the app, it works fine but I get an error from my Visual Studio XAML Designer:

*XDG0062 The resource "DurationOpacity" has an incompatible type.*

I also followed the error link, but I could not find any useful hint for solving this problem. Sometimes it was stated that this is a VS bug.

So, my issue has basically nothing to do with functionality, because it builds and works finde, but I get a huge list of errors (because I am using it like 50 times in my app).

So my questions:

- Do I really use the wrong type for Duration? How can Duration be declared as a StaticResource?
- Has it something to do with VS configurations or missing DLLs oder Nuget Packages?

I am using VS Professional 2019 Version 16.6.1

Thank you for any help or advice!

Comment: You may want to consider cleaning your solution, clearing out VS caches and reopening the project.

Comment: @Rufw91 thank you for your response. I tried clearing out the ComponentModelCache and the Designer Cache. But that did not help. Are there any other caches to consider? Also tried clearing and reopening the solution several times. Always have those 50 errors.

Comment: What type you used ? you should use `System.TimeSpan` as type .. ?

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain I used Duration (System.Windows.Media.Animation.Timeline.Duration) as type. When I declare the StaticResource as TimeSpan and then use it in my Storyboard it throws an XamlParseException telling me: ArgumentException: '00:00:02' is not a valid value for property 'Duration'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814091/in-wpf-animation-set-property-begintime-to-a-static-resource

Comment: check this this the solution to your question ! and it should work.

Comment: It won't work. Because Duration is of type Duration whilst begintime is Timespan. Please try suggestions yourself before posting "this works".

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue.

I put the resources directly in mainwindow and started the storyboard in xaml.

This works fine, no errors.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Duration x:Key="DurationOpacity">0:0:2</Duration>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Listening">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1.0" To="0.3" 
                         Duration="{StaticResource DurationOpacity}" 
                         AutoReverse="True" 
                         RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
    </Storyboard>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red">
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Listening}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

This is vs2019, my solution targets net core 3.1 but I doubt there's been any change that would affect this in 10+ years.

If you create a new solution. Completely new. Throw that markup I posted above in mainwindow. Is that erroring?

If it errors you have a broken install somehow.

It it works then you have a problem elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your effort. I tried and - no errors, worked like a charm. 
I tried several things this afternoon, from deleting the .vs file, the repair-action from VS-Installer, clone the repo again, but nothing helped.